# NIS server make file not found

Tags: makefile, nis

Couldn't build yp data base /var/yp/NIS-kom/ypservers.
Please fix it.
Running /var/yp/Makefile...
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
Error running Makefile.
Please try it by hand.

uninstalled nis and again installed and tried but again make file is missing

Comment: Although `make` is normally used as a programming tool, its use with NIS implementations to rebuild NIS maps is not an exercise in programming, so it borders being off-topic here.  This question would be better suited for [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Whether you move the question or not, it is hard to answer without more details.  What is the exact `make` command line used?  What is your working directory when you run it?  What documentation are you relying upon to choose those details?